# python psycopg2 найти элемент из Базы данных и остановить поиск

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, psycopg2

Хочу написать запрос в БД, чтобы он находил элемент с таким id, и после этого останавливается и не шел дальше искать такой элемент. Что-то типа этого, только чтобы он мне не выдавал True а давал элементы.

```
self.curs.execute(f"SELECT exists (SELECT eng_word, rus_word FROM english_words_date WHERE id = {random_id})")
```

Comment: Два раза перечитал вопрос, ничего не понял.

Answer (score 0):

База данных не может остановиться. Она либо возвращает результаты, либо долго ищет а потом возвращает результаты. Если Вы хотите только 1 результат получить, то нужно использовать `LIMIT 1`.

Например, `self.curs.execute(f"SELECT eng_word, rus_word FROM english_words_date WHERE id = {random_id}" LIMIT 1)`

Но, поскольку, скорее всего запись и так будет одна (id похоже на первичный ключ) то использование `LIMIT 1` в данном случае будет лишним. Но в любом случае,  простыми средствами прервать запрос (сказав - достаточно, верни то, что уже нашел) нельзя.